# Weird differences (with error message) between Firefox and Safari with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, firefox, highcharts, safari

I have a graph which works fine in either Firefox (41.0.2) or Safari (7.1.3) on Mac. The error message in either one of the "problem"-browsers is "http://www.highcharts.com/errors/19 - Too many ticks".

But strangely enough, if I don't put a "tickInterval: 732" in the script, Safari displays it well, Firefox stops with the error message. And if I put it in, it's the inverse, Safari stops with the error message, but Firefox displays it well.

[The fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/cpnzhveu/2/) seems to work fine in both.

Here is the [first version](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/extras/graph_sea_level.php) (Safari doesn't display it, inverse for Firefox), here [the other](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/extras/graph_sea_level_copy.php) (Safari displays it, inverse for Firefox). The only difference is the line "tickInterval: 732"...

Any idea why that would be so?

Comment: Hmm.... Seems that adding "type: 'datetime'" to the xAxis helps. However, then, the xAxis labels are completely different... as one can see [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cpnzhveu/4/).

Comment: Tickinterval should be defined in miliseconds, 732 is almost 1 second,when you have year data.